# No warnings/notification/errors displayed when using typing and assigning wrong values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm new to python and i know that types can't be enforced and the maximum we can do is provide "warnings" . So i'm using `typing` with python3.7 with pycharm professional. But i don't get any warning, notification or indication that i'm using the wrong types. Example:

```
from typing import List

class MyClass:

__event_ids: List[str]

def __init__(self):

    self.__event_ids = 15 <---- This don't react in any way

    return
```

I've researched it, but no tutorial stated any additional steps i need to take to make it work properly

Comment: Type checking for assignments will be released in [2019.1](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-24832) but support for class-level targets has been postponed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html), a standalone type checker.